# Data structure for optimization

Tags: c++, design-patterns, database-design

I am thinking about a method to handle the data more efficiently. Let me explain it:

Currently, there is a class, called `Rules`, it has a lot of member functions, like `Rules::isForwardEligible()`, `Rules::isCurrentNumberEligible()`....So these functions are used to check the specific situations (when other process call them), all of them return bool value.

In the body of these functions are `if`s which will query the DB to compare data, finally return turn or false.

So the whole thing is like `if(Rules::isCurrentNumberEligible())`--->Check content in `Rules::isCurrentNumberEligible()`--->`if(xxxx)`(xxxx will be another function again, query DB), I think this kind way is not good. I want to improve it.

What I am imagining, is to use less code but query more for the information.

So I can query in the first step `if(Rules::isCurrentNumberEligible())`, I can set different tables for query, so the things like `if(xxx){if(xx){if(xx)....}}` will be less. A solutions is to build a class whose role is like a coordinator, ask him each time for different querys. Is it suitable?

I am not sure it is a good way to control this, or may be there are some good solutions aside. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: you could use bitmasks to reduce the number of `if` statements. You could merge all queries into one bitmask, which then could be either checked bit-by-bit, or compared with predefined values. Putting it in a class won't be hard

Comment: It looks like [Guard Clause](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) might help you too.

Comment: Yeah, but this one is almost same as before, I want to use the database or coordinator to handle them.

Comment: It sounds like you might be after having the Rules class have a single method that goes and fetches the relevant data from the DB and caches it in memory.  When the cache is empty or out of date, you do the fetch; otherwise, you use the cached data to save hitting the DB over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

The classical algorithm for rule-based systems is the [RETE algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm). It strives to minimize the number of rules to be evaluated. The trick is that a re-evaluation of a rule does not make sense unless at least one related fact has changed.

In general, those rules should be queried first which promise maximum information gain. This helps to pin-down the respective case in as few questions as possible.
A physician in differential diagnosis would always order his/her questions from general to specific. In information theory this is called the [principle of maximum entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy).